# Xsd.exe Any Type to XmlElement conversion. How to fill generated property?

Tags: c#, serialization, xsd.exe, any

I've an XSD (It's a standard RFC xsd as defined in http://web.rete.toscana.it/eCompliance/portale/dispatcher?from=rfc&pathname=%2Fapps%2Ftsf%2Fdata%2FeCompliance%2FeCRepository%2Frfc%2F0098.06%2F98.6.zip) with an

```
<complexType name="EventoClinico">
    ...
    <sequence>
...
        <element name="Corpo" type="sisrt:Corpo" minOccurs="0" />
    </sequence>
        ...
</complexType>
```

and "Corpo" is

```
<complexType name="Corpo">
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

the xsd.exe tool translate the Corpo Element in a

```
public XmlElement Corpo;
```

property.

The question is:

How can I fill the property with my custom class:

```
public class Example{

public string AString {get;set;}
}
```

How can I set EventoClinico.Corpo = new Example("a string");?

Many Regards.

Francesco.

Here is a solution as suggested in following posts :

```
public XmlElement Convert<TObj>(TObj obj) { 
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TObj)); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings settings= new XmlWriterSettings();
        //settings.ConformanceLevel=ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration=true;
        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
        s.Serialize(w, obj); 
        return ToXmlElement(sb.ToString());
    }

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(string xml)
    {
        XmlDocumentFragment frag = new XmlDocument().CreateDocumentFragment();
        frag.InnerXml = xml;
        return frag.FirstChild as XmlElement;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **any** is not of a strictly defined type, xsd.exe generates XmlElement for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w8zbwa2(v=vs.80).aspx

If you want to put values in there, you're going to need to use the Attributes and ChildNodes collections.

You could have your test class inherit from XmlElement and use get and set of its properties to keep ChildNodes and Attributes in sync with your member data.

```
public class Example : XmlElement {

public string AString {
    get { return GetAttribute("astring"); }

    set { SetAttribute("astring", value); }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide me an Example of what are you thinking?
It looks like the right way.
Regards.

Comment: Mark this as solution (the little check mark) - that lets others know that the solution works, and encourages answerers to pay attention to your questions.

Comment: I think I need also a Constructor
    public  Example(string prefix, string localName, string namespaceURI, XmlDocument doc)
            :base(prefix, localName, namespaceURI, doc)
        {
        
        }

Comment: Sounds right. I wasn't near a machine with a C# compiler when I wrote that example.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... it seems something wrong with your schema, I think type="sisrt:Corpo" shold be type="Corpo" (because it defined as <complexType name="Corpo">)?

Also, if EventoClinico and Corpo are defined in different .xsd files, you may need to use <xs:include schemaLocation="anotherfile.xsd" /> directive

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is a semplification of the real XSD (you can find it on the edited link) and the XSD can't be changed because is a standard. The point is how can I pass an Entity to a XmlElement field?

Comment: Not sure, maybe you could try something like: `public XmlElement Convert<TObj>(TObj obj)
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TObj));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
            s.Serialize(w, obj);
            XmlDocument xe = new XmlDocument();
            xe.ReadNode(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sb.ToString()));
            return (XmlElement)xe.ChildNodes[0];
        }`